# Отследить без ответный WriteFile

Tags: c++-cli

Проблем такова что при определенных условиях файл а именно устройство  перестает отвечать (а команды устройству  все идут и идут) он накапливает в буфере  значения и только при устранении этих "определенных условий" начинает отвечать. Есть может какая то структура или еще что то что бы знать что устройство (файл) отправил но ничего не принял, дабы выполнить очистку буфера устройства и приостановить выполнение программы. Забыл сказать что есть команды которые конфигурируют устройство и ничего не возвращают в замен.

```
 void SendComand(byte byt[]) {
    connectedStatus = CreatePrinter(n);
        if (connectedStatus) {
            try
            {
                OVERLAPPED OverlapWrite;
                OverlapWrite.OffsetHigh = 1;
                OverlapWrite.Offset = 1;
                OverlapWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);

                OVERLAPPED OverlapRead;
                OverlapRead.OffsetHigh = 1;
                OverlapRead.Offset = 1;
                OverlapRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);

                memset(sim, 0, sizeof(sim));

                int sizebyt = sizeof(byt) - 1;
                bool sucsses = WriteFile(ConDevice, (LPCVOID)byt, sizebyt, &ReturnedLength, &OverlapWrite);

                sucsses = ReadFile(ConDevice, &sim, sizeof(sim), &ReturnedLength, &OverlapRead);

                CloseHandle(ConDevice);
                Sleep(20);

                for (int i = OverlapRead.InternalHigh; i < 300; i++) {
                    sim[i] = 0;
                }

            }
            catch (const std::exception&)
            {

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Проверяйте, что ReturnedLength равен размеру записанных данных.

Comment: Однако странный у вас код: дескрипторы событий утекают, все обернуто в `try...catch` хотя C++ исключений тут вроде возникнуть не может, результаты `WriteFile` и `ReadFile` не проверяются, асинхронный ввод / вывод игнорируется.

Comment: И еще у меня возникают подозрения насчет Overlapped-операций и закрытия хэндла до того, как запись реально была произведена...

Comment: Можно подробней про то как проверить результаты записи и чтения и про асинхронных ввод вывод ?